# "pod init" fails with "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to create a Podfile using `pod init`, but it fails every time with  the cryptic error message

> Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

I'm just trying to get my XCode project up and running.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, the simplest answer was best:  I created a file "Gemfile" in the Xcode project directory and added the single line `gem 'cocoapods'` to it.  Then I could install other cocoapods in the usual way.  Not sure what the original problem was, but this fixed it.